# Android : Message sent from seperate thread has obj set to null

Tags: android, multithreading, message

I have a UI created in an activity which creates a handler for receiving messages.

I then launch a second thread for network communication.  This second thread sends messages back to the UI thread via the UI threads handler.

All works OK as long as I send integer values.
However, if I set the `obj`value to an object such as a string, when it arrives in the handler it has been set back to null.

The handler is declared like this :

```
private static class MsgHandler extends Handler
{
    private CommsActivity m_parent;

    public MsgHandler(CommsActivity parent)
    {
        m_parent = parent;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        switch(msg.what)
        {
            case R.integer.msg_progress :
                m_parent.ShowProgress(msg.arg1);
                break;

            case R.integer.msg_error :
                m_parent.ShowError(msg.arg1, (String)msg.obj);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

When I need to send a message from the second thread, I call it in this manner :

```
msg = m_hMsgHandler.obtainMessage();
msg.what = m_iNormalMsgId;
msg.arg1 = R.integer.activation_lockout;
msg.obj = new String(strResponse);
msg.sendToTarget();
```

The `MsgHandler`instance is passed into the thread runnable as a parameter and stored for later use.

I have also tried using a `Bundle` instance, but this also is set to NULL.

Note that I am working with Android 4.4.

What do I need to do to overcome this limitation ?

Comment: your msg.what is m_iNormalMsgId; but you dont handle it in your switch

Comment: @Simon - I built a sample app using as much of your code as I could and the issue was not present.  I suggest you post a complete SSCCE (http://sscce.org) that will help others to see the problem.

Comment: You are quite right - found the bug in my code and corrected it.  Thanks to every one who tried to help here !

Answer (score 0):

try to send message using handler.
hope it helps

```
msg = m_hMsgHandler.obtainMessage();
msg.what = m_iNormalMsgId;
msg.arg1 = R.integer.activation_lockout;
msg.obj = new String(strResponse);
m_hMsgHandler.sendMessage(msg);
```

and check, that you process exactly this message (I see in yuor samples set msg.what = m_iNormalMsgId but in switch process case R.integer.msg_progress like msg.arg1 = R.integer.activation_lockout;)

Comment: Thank you @HiXoid, for you comment.  Just tried this, but it still converts the `msg.obj` to null.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd try it:

```
m_hMsgHandler.sendMessage( 
    m_hMsgHandler.obtainMessage(
        m_iNormalMsgId, 
        R.integer.activation_lockout, 
        0, 
        new String(strResponse)
);
```

Comment: I also tried this method - getting the handler class to fill in the parameters itself, thinking that there could be some thread safe object manipulation being done.  Still did not work.

Comment: crazy theory - maybe this isn't working because String doesn't implement Parcelable? Perhaps try wrapping it in a Bundle object, and setting obj to the Bundle. Although, you might as well use setData(Bundle) at that point.